# interpretation of higher order partial derivatives $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am not able to come up with what $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ would mean in the context of second order partial derivative.

I know what $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ means and let me provide my interpretation of these here:-

$f_{xx} =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial f(x,y) }{\partial x} $ = This is basically , first taking a partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ (that way $y$ gets treated as a constant, meaning its value is fixed, it is not varying). Now since what we got is purely a function of $x$, lets call it $g(x)$. Now since $g(x)$ is just a function of single variable, we just take a regular derivative of $g(x)$ and what we get is what we call as  $f_{xx} =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial f(x,y) }{\partial x} $.

The same logic applies for for $f_{yy}$ -- now instead of $x$ , the same situation is applied to $y$.

But this interpretation fails to take me to either $f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}$. Lets take $f_{yx}$ for example. Here we first calculate $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ with respect to $x$. Once we do that we get some function of $x$ because $y$ is fixed, again lets call it $g(x)$. Now as per what the standard texts say -- in order to calculate $f_{yx}$, the next step is to take derivative of $g(x)$ with respect to $y$. How is that possible? $y$ is not even varying, it's a constant in the context of $g(x)$. So what is the meaning of 'taking derivative of $g(x)$ with respect to $y$'?

The same question applies to $f_{xy}$ as well.

Comment: "*Once we do that we get some function of $x$ because $y$ is fixed, again lets call it $g(x)$.*"  It should technically be called $g(x,y)$.  I withdraw the rest of the comment because it's not different from what you suggested.

Comment: It's important to emphasize that partial derivatives are defined for each point in the domain of the original function, thus also functions of 2 variables.

Comment: There is no replacing of functions in the definitions of derivative and partial. You'll go through your teachers lectures with a fine tooth comb, but not the original definitions in terms of limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to extend my comment into an answer.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.

For each point in $(x_0, y_0)\in U$, we can temporarily "freeze" $y_0$ and observe $f$ as a function of a single variable $x_0$, then defining $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_0, y_0) $ as the derivative of this one-dimentional function.

However, note the key word "for each point" - this freezing happens **locally** for the sake of defining the partial derivative, at each point, not **globally**. 
Therefore $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is absolutely dependent on $y$. It's a function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ just like $f$.